# Get IP address of ISP with PHP

Tags: php, ip-address, php-5.3, php-5.4, php-5.5

If I write in php `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` I get my ip : `176.x.x.x` this address it's equal with the address who I get in cmd written ipconfig.

Now if I write in google find my ip I get another ip : `87.x.x.x`

**The question is:** it's possible to get this ip `87.x.x.x` with php?

Comment: You connected from **local host** and you get your local IPV4 address, because that's what's used to connect over the network to your web server. Had you connected from **internet** and not from **local network**, you'd get the other IP address that you're asking about in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Only thing to do is: place your script in internet on some free/nonfree webhosting.

You get your ip: `176.x.x.x` because this ip is your ip in your local network and you run webserver on your computer (or other computer) which is in local network.

Your local network is connected to internet by router. Router connects 2 networks, so routerwise you have 2 ip addresses: local network ip `(176.x.x.x)` and internet ip `(87.x.x.x)`.
Depending on the webserver location you will get one of these addresses.

When you google your ip, you are looking for it in internet. Webservers placed in internet will see your internet ip address. Btw. Your local network ip is masqueraded by NAT.

Answer (score 0):

The geoip_isp_by_name() function will return the name of the Internet Service Provider (ISP) that an IP is assigned to

```
<?php
$isp = geoip_isp_by_name('www.example.com');
if ($isp) {
echo 'This host IP is from ISP: ' . $isp;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

User the following function to get the client IP. Hope it will work

```
function getClientIP() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Not sure why it was not working for you. And edited the code 1st time i missed to add the return statement.

Comment: Exists a way to get ip from browser?